# Unable to create index because of duplicate that doesn't exist?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, indexing, unique-index

I'm getting an error running the following Transact-SQL command:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_TopicShortName
ON DimMeasureTopic(TopicShortName)
```

The error is:

> Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement
>   terminated because a duplicate key was
>   found for the object name
>   'dbo.DimMeasureTopic' and the index
>   name 'IX_TopicShortName'. The
>   duplicate key value is ().

When I run `SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = 'IX_TopicShortName'` or `SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DimMeasureTopic]')` the IX_TopicShortName index does not display. So there doesn't appear to be a duplicate.

I have the same schema in another database and can create the index without issues there. Any ideas why it won't create here?

Comment: Had this same problem when making a migration that runs when someone updates. i resolved this by first checking for duplicates and deleting them, then checking if the INDEX exists and if not creating it.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

It's not that the index already exists, but that there are duplicate values of the `TopicShortName` field in the table itself.  According to the error message the duplicate value is an empty string (it might just be a facet of posting I guess).  Such duplicates prevent the creation of a `UNIQUE` index.

You could run a query to confirm that you have a duplicate:

```
SELECT
    TopicShortName,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    DimMeasureTopic
GROUP BY
    TopicShortName
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

Presumably in the other database the data are different, and the duplicates are not present.

Comment: This is the 3 time I've googled this error and ended up here so thanks. Also For future reference I'm adding code to delete duplicates. Hope this is ok    DELETE
FROM DimMeasureTopic
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
SELECT MAX(ID)
FROM DimMeasureTopic
GROUP BY TopicShortName)

Answer (score 16):

The duplicate is in your data, try running this query to find it.

```
SELECT TopicShortName, COUNT(*)
FROM DimMeasureTopic
GROUP BY TopicShortName
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 8):

It's because you have records in the table already that are not unique (by the sounds of it, 2 records with a blank value in the TopicShortName field).

So, it's to do with the data, not the index itself.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using code-based migrations, and you rename a property of an entity and you are having an unique index for the property, entity framework will create a new column and trying to add an unique index for the new column but the new column has all null values, therefore it will fail.  You need to manually modify the migration code to copy the data from old column before the line to create index.

Answer (score 0):

It should have specified the duplicate key value in the error message. "The duplicate key value is (' ', ' ', ' ') The statement has been terminated. You have duplicate values that need to be addressed.